# Can I use Creation to create a diamond for a material component?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

I was making a wizard, and I need a diamond, or diamond dust. Am I able to use *creation* to create a giant chunk of rock and then use that chunk to make a (probably rough) diamond? I know I don't have Jeweler's Tools, but I'm more looking for something that I can use for material components for other spells (specifically *chromatic orb*).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## You can create rock or diamond, but not diamond *from* rock.

Part of the [*creation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/creation) spell description says:

> You can also use this spell to create mineral objects such as stone, crystal or metal.

So yes you can create stone and yes you can create diamond. However, there is no way for you (just with this spell) to make a diamond from a lump of stone no matter what tools you have. To have a diamond you have to start with diamond.

## You cannot use any material from *creation* as a spell component

*Creation* says:

> Using any material created by this spell as another spell's material component causes that spell to fail.

So, if you are intending to use the created material for any kind of spell component use, it will not work.

Comment: I do know that I have to be holding a gem/diamond as the component, I was just previously wondering if it was possible to maybe take a chunk of rock from a boulder (in game) and compress it into a gem-form, since they are both stones.

Comment: So if you are asking about taking chunks of rock (that you didn't create using the creation spell) and trying to transform them into diamond that should be asked in a new question since we only do one question per post here. Luckily you can ask as many questions as you want!

Comment: @Dragonman0007 -- Stone and gems are very different minerals, so compressing a stone does not create a gem. Diamond is carbon compressed under very high temperatures.

Comment: I would add that coal and diamonds are more similar the diamond and rock, as diamonds are made out of coal

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Arcane Focus to create a diamond without any pieces of diamond, then sell said diamond and purchase one that was not made with this spell.

PHB *(Page 203)*:

> Material (M)
> Casting some spells requires particular objects, specified in parentheses in the component entry. A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.
> If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.

Comment: Hi Raving Dragoon, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Can you provide support for your statement *"You can use an Arcane Focus to create a diamond without any pieces of diamond"*? It isn't entirely obvious to me from your answer that this is true, and perhaps I missed something but I don't quite understand how the quote you have used supports your point.