# RAW, can Mordekainen's Magnificent Mansion create components for activities/spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Suppose I wanted to repair a *simulacrum*.

Am I able to cast *magnificent mansion* and furnish it such that the materials required to repair the simulacrum are inside the mansion, thus circumventing the cost of repairing the simulacrum?

[*Magnificent mansion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magnificent-mansion) is worded as follows:

> You can create any floor plan you like, but the space can't exceed 50 cubes, each cube being 10 feet on each side. The place is furnished and decorated as you choose.

[*Simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) repairs are worded as follows:

> If the simulacrum is damaged, you can repair it in an alchemical laboratory, using rare herbs and minerals worth 100 gp per hit point it regains.

I would like to:

- Have a greenhouse in the mansion furnished with the rare herbs that I require,
- Have a small mine or mineral vein in the mansion furnished with the rare minerals that I require,
- Have a tool closet in the mansion furnished with the tools that I would need to harvest the aforementioned rare materials, and
- Have some sort of workshop/alchemical laboratory that I can use to perform the repairs?

As a follow-up question, suppose I wanted to cast a spell with expensive material components such as [*gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate), which requires a diamond worth 5,000 gp. Is the mansion able to be created with the diamond already inside so that the caster can simply cast *magnificent mansion*, go inside and then cast *gate* or whatever expensive spell I want?

Comment: Related: [Can the Minor Conjuration ability gained by Wizards of the School of Conjuration be used to summon rare, expensive, consumable spell components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62704/14878), [Can I use Creation to create a diamond for a material component?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131593/14878), [Can an object created by True Polymorph be used as a consumable spell component?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113114/14878)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, not if it’s Read in English (RiE)

> **FURNISH** — fur·nish
>   /ˈfərniSH/
>   verb
>   provide (a house or room) with furniture and fittings.

It has functioning furniture, dresser, armoire, butchers, beds, etc...

> **DECORATE** — dec·o·rate
>   /ˈdekəˌrāt/ verb make (something) look more attractive by adding extra items or images to it.

Paintings, vases, sculptures, etc..

So by these English definitions, you aren’t making a mine shaft with valuable ore nor greenhouse with rare herbs.

The *intent* is a safe haven with food, water and accommodations suitable for basic living needs.  In addition to that, you can make it luxurious with extra decorations.

> Furnishings and other objects created by this spell dissipate into
>   smoke if removed from the mansion.

Per the spell, anything created inside via spell, disappears leaving mansion.

Unlike the rod of security, any specialized room won’t benefit you more than 24 hour period anyways.

As always, subject to change with your DM.  :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite RAW, however I guess the problem is the sentence

> Furnishings and other objects created by this spell dissipate into smoke if removed from the mansion.

in the description of Magnificent Mansion. The main question would be how exactly a repair is done. If I just use conjured tools, say for example hammering out dents in an armor, a repair should stay. If I use conjured materials, for example replacing broken plates in an armor with conjured new ones, the repair will vanish on exit.

Now the description of Simulacrum doesn't tell us which is the case, however I would argue that the repairs will indeed be gone when the simulacrum leaves the mansion, since herbs and minerals sound much more like materials then tools.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, (kind of)

- **Rare herbs:** asks for plant decoration
- **Rare minerals:** asks for furnitures made from the rare minerals (if possible)
- **Tools:** asks for a closet full of the required tools. You can also furnish the mansion as a laboratory

Herbs and mineral veins are not furnitures, so you can't use "furnished" to create the materials.

You also can make a decoration made of diamond or other gem(s).

### However,

I don't think this is the intent of the spell. I'd be very careful to allow this as a DM. Maybe for the first casting of the spell, sure, but not the subsequent casting. As a player, consult your DM, as this is not explicitly stated as allowed, or not allowed.

Answer (score -2):

I imagine a golden gem encrusted bowl for a dining room to get free heros feast might be how you do it more so than “rare herbs” which are arguably not decorations.
I would personally rule that unless an item explicitly has a gold price value such as with bard of creation. If it is temporary, then it has no gold price value. After all even with their perfect physical properties how valuable can your herbs and jewels be if they won’t exist tomorrow and you made them with a spell that cost 15 gold? That makes sense to me, so unlike the spell creation you could decorate it with inexpensive material components and use them for spells. Maybe bring the mistletoe plant in and cut it with a provided golden sickle for druid grove. but you wouldn’t be getting away with getting tangible gold price value out of your magnificent mansion anymore than if you offered it as payment to your planar ally who recognized the realm he is in.

I haven’t heard of any rule or ruling saying otherwise but as a player be reasonable and ask if you can instead of saying that you do because people on the internet said it’s ok. Especially for spells like planeshift material components might have quests based around them or be there intentionally for the dm to take back some his money he loaned you.